# rsync to remote server that does not have the same users setup as local server produces permission error

Tags: freebsd, rsync, linux

I'm setting up a backup of my linux-based webserver to a NAS running FreeBSD.  I've created a backup user on the FreeBSD box and ran rsync as root on the local (web server) box using the following command:

```
rsync -avz /hsphere/ backup_user@192.168.1.253:/mnt/tank/web_backup/web01.webhost.net
```

It works fine for all directories owned by root, but when it starts backing up the directories owned by ordinary users, I get permission denied errors.

```
rsync: recv_generator: mkdir "/mnt/tank/web_backup/web01.webhost.net/hsphere/local/home/username/username.com" failed: Permission denied (13)
```

I was guessing this is because the "-a" tries to preserve the ownership of the original files, and since those users don't exist on the remote server, it was refusing it.  I tried running rsync without the -o -g and -p flags thinking that would get around it, but I get the same error.

```
rsync -rltDz /hsphere/ backup_user@192.168.1.253:/mnt/tank/web_backup/web01.webhost.net
```

If I rsync using root for the remote NAS, it does succeed, but I would rather not have to use root on the NAS if I can avoid it since it creates a security hole.  The "backup_user" on the freebsd box is in the wheel group, which should give him sufficient permissions.

Any advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to try `--fake-super`. From the `rsync` [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync):

**`--fake-super`**

> When this option is enabled, rsync simulates super-user activities by saving/restoring the privileged attributes via special extended attributes that are attached to each file (as needed). This includes the file's owner and group (if it is not the default), the file's device info (device & special files are created as empty text files), and any permission bits that we won't allow to be set on the real file (e.g. the real file gets u-s,g-s,o-t for safety) or that would limit the owner's access (since the real super-user can always access/change a file, the files we create can always be accessed/changed by the creating user).

In your case, since you want to use `--fake-super` on the remote side, you will need to invoke it via `--rsync-path`, e.g.:

```
rsync -avz --rsync-path='rsync --fake-super' /source/ backupuser@remote:/dest/
```

When restoring from your backups, you will also need to ensure that `--fake-super` is always in force on the system where the backups are stored.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I got the same error with the fake-super added in though.

Comment: @John P: Is it possible that you have a previous partially-completed backup interfering with your latest attempt? If so, remove your entire backup directory tree and try again with `--fake-super`.